# moving data from one listbox (data from database) to another listbox in same page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help me ,I am very new to asp.net.I have one Listbox, on which data has been taken from the database, I want to move this data into another Listbox one by one ,what is ASP.Net c# code for this?
thanks in advance..

Comment: Any efforts from your side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListBox2.Items.AddRange(ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToArray());
```

you need to add `using` statement to

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Comment: object[] items = new object[listBox1.Items.Count];  my code showing error on this point

Comment: ListBox2.Items.AddRange(items) showing error that method Addrange has some invalid arguement